# Ckan 2.9 customizing CSS

Tags: css, customization, ckan

I followed the [Ckan-2.9 theming guide](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/theming/css.html) to customize CSS. I followed the process adding a static file (not using webassets). Everything works fine except that the css modification isn't taken into account. I checked several times and can't see where this is coming from. In parallel, I found inspiration on a [custom ckan](https://github.com/AQUACROSS/ckanext-aquacross_theme/tree/master/ckanext/aquacross_theme) close to what I want to get, but that didn't solve my problem either.

Had someone similar difficulties when customizing ckan's css? What can be the reasons ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that the modifications made by the extension were active but constrained by the main CSS. For example, the hero image has a max-size constraint that hides the image added with our extention.