# ckan 2.9 - Customizing CKAN’s CSS

Tags: ckan

A related question is already here ([ckan-2-9-customizing-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65141981/ckan-2-9-customizing-css)).

I followed the steps at [Customizing CKAN’s CSS](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/theming/css.html). Unfortunately I did not get the changes which shall be visible. The changed colors are responded from the server, but for any reason these get overloaded/constrained by something.
Anybody have an idea how to get the extension CSS settings used?

Comment: Do you have any extensions enabled?

Comment: I use the following plugins: ckan.plugins = stats text_view image_view recline_view datastore example_theme